# NodeJS Pass data from current page to another

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want to make a User management system in Node. I have a page where all users are listed in a table. After I press the edit button, it should go to the user page with all the information of that user. But I don't know how to pass the username into my Node function.

This is my table for the users. the `Benutzerverwaltung_Mitareiter` is the page where the information from the user is getting shown

```
<tbody>
    <%for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=users[i].username%></td>
        <td><%=users[i].admin%></td>
        <td>
            <form action="/users/Benutzerverwaltung_Mitarbeiter">
                <button id="buttonAnzeigen" 
                        type="submit"
                        name="username" 
                        href="" 
                        value="<%users[i].username%>" 
                        data-toggle="tooltip" 
                        title="Anzeigen">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%}%>
</tbody>
```

I passed the username of the user into the value of the button.

And this is how I get the data for the table

```
router.route ('/Benutzerverwaltung_Mitarbeiter').get(function (req, res) {
    const username = req.body;
    User.find(function (err, users) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err);
        res.render('Benutzerverwaltung_Mitarbeiter',{
            users: users || [],

        });

    });
});
```

If someone can help me to get the function, I would be very thankful!

Comment: _get the function_ is seeming confusing. Can you please explain bit more about it?

Comment: So I'm reading all the data of my user collection in my database and put them into an array. after that, I'm reading the array in my EJS file and loop them into my table.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use some template engine, like [ejs](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) or [jade](http://jade-lang.com/). This form, you can use [res.render](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html) and send json information for view. For more details consult the engine docs and res.render doc too.

Comment: I'm working with ejs but don't know how to pass data in my app js

Comment: ejs.renderFile(filename, data, options, function(err, str){
    // str => Rendered HTML string
});

Comment: is the data the value of the element where the data is?